# For loop for column calculations

Tags: python

I am new to Python, do not know how to create for loop for calculations on multiple columns. 
I need to do the following calculations on multiple columns:

```
cal_1=df1.groupby(['Type'])['Ind_1'].sum()/df1.groupby(['Type'])['ID'].count()

cal_2=df1.groupby(['Type'])['Ind_2'].sum()/df1.groupby(['Type'])['ID'].count()

....

cal_20=df1.groupby(['Type'])['Ind_20'].sum()/df1.groupby(['Type'])['ID'].count()
```

How can I achieve it by using for loop?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
cal = []
for i in range(1,21):
    cal.append(df1.groupby(['Type'])['Ind_' + str(i)].sum()/df1.groupby(['Type'])['ID'].count())
```

Then, the results are stored as a list in `cal`.

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering if there is any way to name the series in the list, such as cal1, cal2 , so that I can identify the values.

Comment: `cal[i-1]` for whatever index `i` you want will work.